# Discretionary line breaks in math mode and appropriate hyphen

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I've got a document where I have some issues with line breaks. I've got three pairs of math-mode terms, separated with hyphens and with parentheses around two of the terms. I want it to break only between a right parenthesis and a left parenthesis. How do I do that, and what is the most appropriate choice of hyphen, e.g., -, em, en. Also, is it better to put the outer hyphend in the Math-mode text rather than adjacent to it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
A long line of  text written in order to see where the construction breaks.
($fooleft$-$fooright$-)%
($barleft$-$barright$)%
(-$bazleft$-$bazright$)
\end{document}
```

Based on a suggestion from egreg I changed the markup and it almost works, but it puts extraneous space between terms:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\donotbreak} {m}
    {
      \mbox{#1}\discretionary{}{}{}%
    }

\NewDocumentCommand{\nobreaks} {>{\SplitList{,}}m}
    {
      \ProcessList{#1}{\donotbreak}
    }

\begin{document}
A long line of  text written in order to see where the construction breaks.
\nobreaks
  {%
    ($fooleft$-$fooright$-),%
    $barleft$-$barright$,%
    -($bazleft$-$bazright$)
  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have unprotected end-of-lines in the definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the parenthesized parts in a box, so it can't be split; between them we can use `\discretionary{}{}{}` to allow a line break.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\bunchofparens}{>{\SplitList{,}}m}{%
  \ProcessList{#1}{\makeparens}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\makeparens}{m}{%
  \mbox{(#1)}\discretionary{}{}{}%
}

\begin{document}

Text written to see where the construction breaks.
\bunchofparens{$fooleft$-$fooright$-,$barleft$-$barright$,-$bazleft$-$bazright$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm already using xparse, but I hadn't looked at argument processors yet. What about the secondary question; should I be using -, or would it look better with --, --- or $-$, and should I be using the same dash within and between pairs. Thanks.

Comment: @shmuel That's a question of taste. No idea, without seeing a “real world” example.

Comment: One example is https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1906/1906.11690.pdf on page 61.

Comment: @shmuel Definitely a hyphen.

Comment: Please see my edit; I'm getting extraneous space. Would it be easier to do things with a clist variable and concatenate all of the markup?

Comment: I get an extraneous space from my test case in my last edit, but essentially the same code seems to work in the actual paper.